# Do I have a disorder? (See description)

Tags: mental-health, disorders

Now, it is hard to explain for me. But I need to know what is this. Because I have no idea what this is, I might over-explain. I tried Google with lots of different phrases, and it seems as if this needs some human help.

**tl;dr: This is related to getting annoyed when lots of stuff is happening. Because of my specific life, this mostly happens when I'm working on my computer.**

So basically I get annoyed when lots of different programs are open, or I'm doing lots of different things all with lots of specific details. Instead of tackling a problem step-by-step, sometimes you need to do a lot at once, mostly due to time constraints. For example, as a content writer, sometimes I open five Microsoft Word windows and as I type different things about the same topic, I choose which file to put that piece of content in.

- Suppose I create different headings in all of those, and I also have to do some formatting. This becomes **"too much"** too quickly and I'm on the verge of crushing my teeth into each other.
- Perhaps I can't do multitasking, but there's more to it. I can't stand the sight of a **computer screen with tons of icons**. On my desktop, there are just 5 and that too set in small size. The rest of the screen is empty, mostly pure black. **This makes me relaxed**.
- I can't handle it (mentally) **when lots of tabs are open**. I must close what I don't need to feel okay and continue. If, due to some reason, I open a lot of tabs, the **"chaos"** makes me **extremely annoyed, unhappy, agitated, and aggressive**.
- Suppose I have **two workspaces open** -- one where I am doing some downloading, some disk cleanup, and an antivirus scan -- and on the other one, I am doing some college work that requires at least two software and four to five folders open. This exact situation is what **I can't take**. Once I clear up the college work and close that workspace, I feel *much* relieved. This relief is uncommon, nobody should feel so much of it for such a small thing.

In all the mentioned stuff, I can "do" it easily, but I start clenching my teeth while doing such jobs. I start shaking my head every once a while, as if I'm "refreshing" myself to handle the chaos. 
I think I have a disorder, and not knowing what it is just makes me even more annoyed. I am sure somebody here knows what exactly I have. Thanks.

Comment: Requests for personal medical advice are off topic here.

Answer (score 3):

You can't make a diagnosis based on a few behaviours, let alone on a forum.

If you feel these experiences are interfering with your daily life, then seek professional help - perhaps your doctor or mental health professional (e.g., clinical psychologist, psychiatrist, or psychotherapist).

Comment: Welcome to Health! Be sure to take our [tour]. *You can't make a diagnosis based on a few behaviours, let alone on a forum*. This plus the obligatory *visit your doctor* are the only valid responses as was decided on [meta]. Your answer should be no more than that. Actually, you are not supposed to answer a question requesting diagnosis at all, but provide a comment instead.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I have amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: @CareyGregory Same here. The answer actually turned from -2 to +2, which is always great to see. Thanks a lot for doing the edit, PyjamaNinja, it really improved the answer.

Comment: No problem. Thank you both for kindly taking the time to explain what an appropriate answer should look like.